# How to get wpf datagrid selected row value?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

```
var Id = AccMgtgrid.SelectedItems;
```

I getting the result below

[image]

But I have to separately return the value **4785**. What should I to for that.

Comment: Is `Id` is an array? `Id[0].AccountID` ??

Comment: Is your datagrid `SelectionMode` set to `Single` or `Extended`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have allowed user to select multiple rows. You cannot get a single value if you have allowed SelectionMode to Extended.

If you set SelectionMode to single then do this.

**[Edit]**

```
int accountId;
var selectedRow = AccMgtgrid.SelectedItem;
if (selectedRow != null)
    accountId = selctedRow.AccountId;
```

**[/Edit]**

And if you had allowed multiple rows then do this.

```
List <int> idList = new List<int>();
var results = AccMgtgrid.SelectedItems;
foreach (var result in results)
    idList.Add(result.AccountID);
```

This will give u list of all accounts ids which user has selected.

Comment: if use this(var result = AccMgtgrid.SelectedItem.AccountID;) means, error(object does not contain defination for AccountID) showing

Comment: This is happening because you haven't set SelectionMode to single. If you had changed the SelectionMode then what intellisense shows when you place a dot(.) after AccMgtgrid.SelectedItem. Does it show other properties like date or name.

Comment: check my edit in the answer. But make sure you have changed SelectionMode to single, else it will not work.